# Deleting attributes and empty elements

Tags: xslt

In an XSL transformation, there are two things I have not been able to figure out.
In the source XML

```
<Network>
  <Hosts>
    <Host modelId="1" name="H1">
      <LinPorts>
        <LinPort name="Port3" speed="100" parent="H1"/>
      </LinPorts>
      <CanPorts/>
      <EthernetPorts>
        <EthernetPort name="Port1" speed="100" parent="H1"/>
        <EthernetPort name="Port2" speed="100" parent="H1"/>
      </EthernetPorts>
    </Host>
    <Host modelId="1" name="H2">
      <CanPorts>
        <CanPort name="Port2" speed="100" parent="H2"/>
      </CanPorts>
      <EthernetPorts>
        <EthernetPort name="Port1" speed="100" parent="H3"/>
      </EthernetPorts>
    </Host>
    <Host modelId="1" name="lin">
      <LinPorts>
        <LinPort name="Port1" speed="10" parent="lin"/>
        <LinPort name="Port2" speed="100" parent="H2"/>
        <LinPort name="Port3" speed="100" parent="lin"/>
      </LinPorts>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>
  <DataFrames>
    <DataFrame bitSize="21" name="greasd" offset="0.021" period="0.021" prio="0">
      <Path name="greasd-S5" parent="greasd">
        <Node name="H1" sequenceNumber="1" parent="greasd-S5"/>
        <Node name="S5" sequenceNumber="2" parent="greasd-S5"/>
      </Path>
    </DataFrame>
    <DataFrame bitSize="23" name="hytdsg" offset="0.423" period="0.423" prio="0">
      <Path name="hytdsg-H1" parent="hytdsg">
        <Node name="H2" sequenceNumber="1" parent="hytdsg-H1"/>
        <Node name="S5" sequenceNumber="2" parent="hytdsg-H1"/>
        <Node name="H1" sequenceNumber="3" parent="hytdsg-H1"/>
      </Path>
    </DataFrame>
  </DataFrames>
</Network>
```

some child nodes have been incorrectly placed. I am using the attribute @parent to place them correctly. This works well using the XSLT below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- Copy all nodes (that do not get a better match) as they are -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Host">
    <xsl:variable name="hostname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <LinPorts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//LinPorts/LinPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                 <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </LinPorts>
        <CanPorts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//CanPorts/CanPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                 <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </CanPorts>
         <EthernetPorts>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="//EthernetPorts/EthernetPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                 <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </EthernetPorts>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataFrame">
    <xsl:variable name="framename" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Path[@parent=$framename]">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Path">
    <xsl:variable name="pathname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node[@parent=$pathname]">
            <xsl:sort select="@sequenceNumber" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  Do not save attributes parent and ID for child elements -->
<xsl:template match="CanPort|LinPort|EthernetPort|Node">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='parent') and not(name()='id')]">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. I also create elements that are empty (CanPorts, LinPorts, EthernetPorts). How do I get rid of these?
2. I want to get rid of the @parent attribute. I have managed to do so for all elements except Path. How do I get rid of Path.parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 1, you can use an `xsl:if` to check the count of LinPort, CanPort, and EthernetPort before creating LinPorts, CanPorts, and EthernetPorts elements
And for 2, add another template that matches `@parent` and does nothing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Host">
    <xsl:variable name="hostname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(//LinPorts/LinPort[@parent=$hostname]) != 0">
            <LinPorts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//LinPorts/LinPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </LinPorts>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="count(//CanPorts/CanPort[@parent=$hostname]) != 0">
            <CanPorts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//CanPorts/CanPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </CanPorts>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="count(//EthernetPorts/EthernetPort[@parent=$hostname]) != 0">
            <EthernetPorts>
                <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="//EthernetPorts/EthernetPort[@parent=$hostname]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </EthernetPorts>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataFrame">
    <xsl:variable name="framename" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Path[@parent=$framename]">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Path">
    <xsl:variable name="pathname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node[@parent=$pathname]">
            <xsl:sort select="@sequenceNumber" data-type="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  Do not save attributes parent and ID for child elements -->
<xsl:template match="CanPort|LinPort|EthernetPort|Node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- This template matches @parent and @id and does nothing -->
<xsl:template match="@parent | @id"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```